# azure api manager terraform queries

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, vnet

I am planning to use azurerm_api_management with the help of terraform. 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/api_management.html

- unable to find reference to integrate it with vnet and subnet for my
  backend services.
- how can we provide our own custom domain name to
  azure api manager so that these REST API accessible over this URL e.g. api.dev.mycompany.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom hostnames support should be there, see here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/api_management.html argument hostname_configuration defines how you can specify custom hostnames for different APIM endpoints.

As for VNET integration, seems they're working on it: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/2582

Comment: yes i know how to do this things manually but i am unable to find reference for same through Azure terraform documentation

Comment: Ah, my bad. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To have your own domain name (custom domain) for Api Management by using Terraform, I'm using the following script to have custom domain name for the Developer Portal and Proxy (the api). You can also have your own name for Management and SCM.

This scipt require that you have a pfx (certificate), named `letsencrypt.pfx` in same directory as you Terraform script.

```
    resource "azurerm_api_management" "mngmnt" {
      name                = "ApiManagementTest"
      location            = "northeurope"
      resource_group_name = "ApiManagement--rg"
      publisher_name      = "Api pubisher"
      publisher_email     = "contact@publisher.com"

      hostname_configuration {
        portal =  [{
          host_name = "api-portal.customdomain.com"
          certificate = "${base64encode(file("letsencrypt.pfx"))}"
          certificate_password  = "topSecretPwd123"
        }]
        proxy = [{
          host_name = "api.customdomain.com"
          certificate = "${base64encode(file("letsencrypt.pfx"))}"
          certificate_password  = "topSecretPwd123"
        }]
      }

      sku {
        name     = "Developer"
        capacity = "1"
      }
    }
```

To have custom domain work you must also remember to add a CNAME record in your public DNS to the following:

api-portal.customdomain.com -> [your name of the Api Management].portal.azure-api.net
api.customdomain.com -> [your name of the Api Management].azure-api.net

Example by using name from our script, it would be:

api-portal.customdomain.com -> ApiManagementTest.portal.azure-api.net

api.customdomain.com -> ApiManagementTest.azure-api.net